# Remove lines from text file if it starts with

Tags: powershell

I have large text files that contain invalid records.

I would like to remove all lines where the first field is blank. The file delimiter is a tilde , so essentially I want to remove all lines where the first character is ~

Can someone assist with the PowerShell code - I cannot seem to get it right.

Comment: How large is your file? What have you tried and in what ways did it not succeed? Have you tried, for example, Get-Content file.txt | Where { $_ -notmatch "^~" } | Set-Content filteredfile.txt?

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly - I was missing the ^

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just adding the answer part from my comment as an answer, so that people can see that the question has been answered.

The solution which worked from the person asking the question was:

```
Get-Content file.txt | Where { $_ -notmatch "^~" } | Set-Content filteredfile.txt
```

As a note, be aware of potential encoding issues. If you need to specify encoding, both the `Get-Content` and the `Set-Content` methods have an `-Encoding` parameter which you can use to specify encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can also do it this way:

```
sls -n '^~' file.txt | set-content filtered.txt
```

Comment: I got weird `C:\temp\left.cs:1:` prefixes on every line doing this.