# How to delete lines that start with "#" in a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, search

Every morning I have a report that generates a CSV file that contains names of computers, as well as additional comments throughout the file. Each line that is a comment starts with "#", and comments are scattered throughout the document, not just at the start of the document so I can't just read over the first couple lines.

Is there any way to search through the CSV file and delete lines that start with "#"? Or is there a way to select lines that don't start with "#", and save them to as a new file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove lines from text file if it starts with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109082/remove-lines-from-text-file-if-it-starts-with)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely.

You could read the file, line by line, and simply filter out anything that starts with `#`:

```
Get-Content $csvPath |Where-Object {$_ -notlike '#*'} |Set-Content $newCsvPath
```

Comment: If there might be one or more spaces or tabs before the `#`, you can use `{ $_ -notmatch '^\s*#' }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($thing in $csv) {
    if ($thing.StartsWith("#")) {
        continue
     } else {
        #insert what you want to do here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750456/) mentioned that you also want to filter out empty lines. This will do that:

```
Get-Content "inputfile.csv" |
  Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '(^\s*$)|(^\s*#)' } |
  Set-Content "outputfile.csv"
```