# How to delete lines in a CSV that start with "#" or are blank | PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, import, powershell-ise

I have a CSV file that contains nearly 4,000+ lines, with random blank lines and comments starting with "#" throughout. I'm trying to import the CSV file while skipping lines that are blank or start with "#". I've tried this:

```
$csvFile = Import-Csv .\example.csv | Where-Object {$_ -notlike '#*'} | Where-Object {$_ -ne ''}
```

and this does not work. I've also tried:

```
$csvFile = Import-Csv .\example.csv
Get-Content $csvFile | Where-Object {$_ -notlike '#*' | Where-Object {$_ -ne ''} | Set-Content newCSV.csv
```

Both of these result in the file being imported with all lines, and nothing has changed from the original. Is there a better way to do this? I'm stumped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete lines that start with "#" in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710093/how-to-delete-lines-that-start-with-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: Correct, it is a duplicate. But none of the answers in that thread worked, and no one was responding anymore.

Comment: You did not mention empty lines in your original question. See my answer there that also filters out empty lines.

Comment: Incidentally - the OR logical operator in PowerShell is `-or`, not `|`. (The `|` is only used to create a pipeline.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
Get-Content $csvPath | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^#|^$' } | Set-Content $strippedCsvPath
```

`^#` matches line starting with #, `^$` matches empty line.

You can simplify testing using following snippet:

```
$csv = 'line1',
'#line2',
'',
'line4'

$csv | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^#|^$' }
```

If whitespaces are (un)important, if empty lines means lines containing only whitespaces, you can slightly change RegEx to `^\s*#|^\s*$` as follows:

```
$csv = 'line1',
'#line2',
'',
'    ',
'   #comment',
'line4'

$csv | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\s*#|^\s*$' }
```

Comment: You might consider also updating your regex to account for whitespace before `#` and/or whitespace-only lines.